# check if password was used before using Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

We are trying to build a web application using Laravel 5 and I'm wondering if it's possible to prevent the users from using the last 5 passwords.

We were thinking of creating a password history table where we save old passwords whenever a user register/reset password and then check the new password against the old ones in the ResetPasswordController.

Would this method work or we should write our own Auth classes ?

Comment: Which version of laravel are you using? I don't believe Laravel supports anything like that out of the box, but you should be able to extend / override the auth stuff to achieve your goal.

Comment: we are going to use Laravel 5

Comment: This is absolutely possible. Give it a few tries! should be pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is create the proper relationships a user would have for that passwords table.

Every time a user creates or changes a password run it against a the last 5 passwords for that user.

This can sometimes be annoying for users but large sites use it as a good safety feature. Good Luck!